# Integration with mail and python application raising SMTP error

Tags: python, gmail, integration, gmail-imap

I am not being able to integrate between gmail and python application. My 2step authentication is on, so I have enabled account access and app password is on, have also enabled IMAP access. Yet I am getting SMTP response error: (334, b'UGFzc3dvcmQ6')

While trying first to run this code, security alert email I am getting, I have accessed allow option, yet the error is still showing.
I am not sure whether my code is throwing error or their any bug present.
This is my code:

....

```
import os
....import smtplib
....from email.message import EmailMessage

....EMAIL_ADDRESS= os.environ.get('Email_User')
....EMAIL_PASSWORD= os.environ.get('Email_Password')

....msg= EmailMessage()
....msg['Subject']= 'Testing email.'
....msg['From']= EMAIL_ADDRESS
....msg['To']= 'orchidlight09@gmail.com'
....msg.set_content('This is a test email.')
   

....with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465) as smtp:
    
 ....   smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS,EMAIL_PASSWORD)
    
  ....  smtp.send_message(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way as well, if it did not workout properly, change the port to 465..

```
import os
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

EMAIL_ADDRESS= os.environ.get('Email_User')
EMAIL_PASSWORD= os.environ.get('Email_Password')

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject']= 'Testing email.'
msg['From']= EMAIL_ADDRESS
msg['To']= 'orchidlight09@gmail.com'
msg.set_content('This is a test email.')
   
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.starttls()
s.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).